# Mi formulario de contacto no funciona en otros hostings

Tags: php, javascript, json, phpmailer, hosting

El problema es que mi formulario funciona perfectamente en un hosting de "ukoo.mx/SNX/contacto2.php" pero ese mismo contacto lo pase sin cambio alguno a "sanext.mx/contacto2.php" y no manda los mensajes aunque la notificación muestra que si se mando, no entiendo que sucede, si es una mala configuración de hosting de sanext.mx :/

**UPDATE**
Claro, yo asumi que por lo mismo que funcionaba en el hosting de ukoo el problema estaba en el hosting de sanext y por eso no incluí el codigo pero se los comparto a continuación:

Formulario de contacto

```html
<section class="section section-sm section-last bg-default text-md-left">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row row-50">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <h4 class="text-spacing-50">Formulario de contacto</h4>
              <form class="rd-form rd-mailform" data-form-output="form-output-global" data-form-type="contact" method="post" action="bat/rd-mailform.php">
                <div class="row row-14 gutters-14">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="form-wrap">
                      <input class="form-input" id="contact-first-name" type="text" name="name" data-constraints="@Required">
                      <label class="form-label" for="contact-first-name">Nombre</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="form-wrap">
                      <input class="form-input" id="contact-email" type="email" name="email" data-constraints="@Email @Required">
                      <label class="form-label" for="contact-email">Correo electrónico</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="form-wrap">
                      <label class="form-label" for="contact-message">Mensaje</label>
                      <textarea class="form-input" id="contact-message" name="message" data-constraints="@Required"></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <button class="button button-primary button-pipaluk" type="submit">Enviar</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

rd-mailform.php

```
<?php

$formConfigFile = file_get_contents("rd-mailform.config.json");
$formConfig = json_decode($formConfigFile, true);

date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

try {
    require './phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $recipients = $formConfig['recipientEmail'];

    preg_match_all("/([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)/", $recipients, $addresses, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

    if (!count($addresses[0])) {
        die('MF001');
    }

    function getRemoteIPAddress() {
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
            return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];

        } else if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
            return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }
        return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    if (preg_match('/^(127\.|192\.168\.|::1)/', getRemoteIPAddress())) {
        die('MF002');
    }

    $template = file_get_contents('rd-mailform.tpl');

    if (isset($_POST['form-type'])) {
        switch ($_POST['form-type']){
            case 'contact':
                $subject = 'Un mensaje del visitante de su sitio.';
                break;
            case 'subscribe':
                $subject = 'Solicitud de suscripción';
                break;
            case 'order':
                $subject = 'Solicitud de orden';
                break;
            default:
                $subject = 'Un mensaje del visitante de su sitio';
                break;
        }
    }else{
        die('MF004');
    }

    if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $template = str_replace(
            array("<!-- #{FromState} -->", "<!-- #{FromEmail} -->"),
            array("Correo electrónico:", $_POST['email']),
            $template);
    }

    if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
        $template = str_replace(
            array("<!-- #{MessageState} -->", "<!-- #{MessageDescription} -->"),
            array("Mensaje:", $_POST['message']),
            $template);
    }

    // In a regular expression, the character \v is used as "anything", since this character is rare
    preg_match("/(<!-- #\{BeginInfo\} -->)([^\v]*?)(<!-- #\{EndInfo\} -->)/", $template, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if ($key != "counter" && $key != "email" && $key != "message" && $key != "form-type" && $key != "g-recaptcha-response" && !empty($value)){
            $info = str_replace(
                array("<!-- #{BeginInfo} -->", "<!-- #{InfoState} -->", "<!-- #{InfoDescription} -->"),
                array("", ucfirst($key) . ':', $value),
                $matches[0][0]);

            $template = str_replace("<!-- #{EndInfo} -->", $info, $template);
        }
    }

    $template = str_replace(
        array("<!-- #{Subject} -->", "<!-- #{SiteName} -->"),
        array($subject, $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']),
        $template);

    $mail = new PHPMailer();


    if ($formConfig['useSmtp']) {
        //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
        $mail->isSMTP();

        //Enable SMTP debugging
        // 0 = off (for production use)
        // 1 = client messages
        // 2 = client and server messages
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

        $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

        // Set the hostname of the mail server
        $mail->Host = $formConfig['host'];

        // Set the SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
        $mail->Port = $formConfig['port'];

        // Whether to use SMTP authentication
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";

        // Username to use for SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = $formConfig['username'];

        // Password to use for SMTP authentication
        $mail->Password = $formConfig['password'];
    }

    $mail->From = $_POST['email'];

    # Attach file
    if (isset($_FILES['file']) &&
        $_FILES['file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
            $_FILES['file']['name']);
    }

    if (isset($_POST['name'])){
        $mail->FromName = "SanexT | " .$subject;
    }else{
        $mail->FromName = "Visitante";
    }

    foreach ($addresses[0] as $key => $value) {
        $mail->addAddress($value[0]);
    }

    $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->MsgHTML($template);
    $mail->send();

    die('MF000');
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    die('MF254');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('MF255');
}
```

rd-mailform.config.json

```
{
  "useSmtp": false,
  "host": "mail.gawa.mx",
  "port": 465,
  "username": "contacto@sanext.mx",
  "password": "*********",
  "recipientEmail": "contacto@sanext.mx"
}
```

PHPMailerAutoload.php

```
<?php
/**
 * PHPMailer SPL autoloader.
 * PHP Version 5
 * @package PHPMailer
 * @link https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/ The PHPMailer GitHub project
 * @author Marcus Bointon (Synchro/coolbru) <phpmailer@synchromedia.co.uk>
 * @author Jim Jagielski (jimjag) <jimjag@gmail.com>
 * @author Andy Prevost (codeworxtech) <codeworxtech@users.sourceforge.net>
 * @author Brent R. Matzelle (original founder)
 * @copyright 2012 - 2014 Marcus Bointon
 * @copyright 2010 - 2012 Jim Jagielski
 * @copyright 2004 - 2009 Andy Prevost
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/lesser.html GNU Lesser General Public License
 * @note This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful - WITHOUT
 * ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
 */

/**
 * PHPMailer SPL autoloader.
 * @param string $classname The name of the class to load
 */
function PHPMailerAutoload($classname)
{
    //Can't use __DIR__ as it's only in PHP 5.3+
    $filename = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'class.'.strtolower($classname).'.php';
    if (is_readable($filename)) {
        require $filename;
    }
}

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.1.2', '>=')) {
    //SPL autoloading was introduced in PHP 5.1.2
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '>=')) {
        spl_autoload_register('PHPMailerAutoload', true, true);
    } else {
        spl_autoload_register('PHPMailerAutoload');
    }
} else {
    /**
     * Fall back to traditional autoload for old PHP versions
     * @param string $classname The name of the class to load
     */
    function spl_autoload_register($classname)
    {
        PHPMailerAutoload($classname);
    }
}
```

rd-mailform.tpl

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <title><!-- #{Subject} --></title>
    <style type="text/css">  
    #outlook a {
      padding: 0;
    }
    body {
      width: 100% !important;
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .ExternalClass {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .ExternalClass,
    .ExternalClass span,
    .ExternalClass font,
    .ExternalClass td,
    .ExternalClass div {
      line-height: 100%;
    }
    .ExternalClass p {
      line-height: inherit;
    }
    #body-layout {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100% !important;
      line-height: 100% !important;
    }
    img {
      display: block;
      outline: none;
      text-decoration: none;
      -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
    }
    a img {
      border: none;
    }
    table td {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
      mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
    }
    a {
      color: orange;
      outline: none;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body id="body-layout" style="background: #406c8d;">
    <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 0 15px;background: #406c8d;">
          <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
              <td height="15" style="height: 15px; line-height:15px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="600" align="center" valign="top" style="border-radius: 4px; overflow: hidden; box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);background: #dde1e6;">
                <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top" style="border-top-left-radius: 4px; border-top-right-radius: 4px; overflow: hidden; padding: 0 20px;background: #302f35;">
                      <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                          <td height="30" style="height: 30px; line-height:30px;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 32px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 32px; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: 1px;color: #ffffff;">Nueva notificación</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td height="30" style="height: 30px; line-height:30px;"></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 0 20px;">
                      <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                          <td height="30" style="height: 30px; line-height:30px;"></td>
                        </tr> 
                        <tr> 
                          <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 22px; font-weight: 400;color: #302f35;">Hola, alguien te dejó un mensaje en <!-- #{SiteName} --></td> 
                        </tr>
                        <tr> 
                          <td height="20" style="height: 20px; line-height:20px;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" valign="top">
                            <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="background: #d1d5da;">
                                  <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                    <tr>
                                      <td height="1" style="height: 1px; line-height:1px;"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="background: #e4e6e9;">
                                  <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                    <tr>
                                      <td height="2" style="height: 2px; line-height:2px;"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td height="20" style="height: 20px; line-height:20px;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 24px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 30px; font-weight: 700;color: #302f35;">
                            <!-- #{Subject} -->
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td height="20" style="height: 20px; line-height:20px;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" valign="top">
                            <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                  <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                    <tr>
                                      <td width="110" align="left" valign="top" style="padding: 0 10px 0 0;font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400;color: #302f35;font-weight: 700;"><!-- #{FromState} --></td>
                                      <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400;color: #302f35;"><!-- #{FromEmail} --></td> 
                                    </tr> 
                                    <!-- #{BeginInfo} -->
                                    <tr> 
                                      <td width="110" align="left" valign="top" style="padding: 0 10px 0 0;font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400;color: #302f35;font-weight: 700;"><!-- #{InfoState} --></td>
                                      <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400;color: #302f35;"><!-- #{InfoDescription} --></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <!-- #{EndInfo} -->                                    
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td height="12" style="height: 12px; line-height:12px;"></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400;color: #302f35;font-weight: 700;"><!-- #{MessageState} --></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400;color: #302f35;">
                                <!-- #{MessageDescription} -->   
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td height="40" style="height: 40px; line-height:40px;"></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="20" style="height: 20px; line-height:20px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="600" align="center" valign="top">
                <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 18px; font-weight: 400;color: #a1b4c4;">Este es un correo electrónico generado automáticamente, por favor no responda.</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="20" style="height: 20px; line-height:20px;"></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Espero que me puedan apoyar con esto :(

Comment: No muestras código, tampoco soy experto en php, pero si no has cambiado nada en contacto2.php supongo que te está fallando que tienes aún configurado el correo del antiguo dominio, en el caso de que estés usando credenciales de correo `@ukoo.mx` para el envío, te recomiendo crear el nuevo correo electrónico `@sanext.mx` y realizar la edición en el archivo contacto2.php

Comment: Por favor coloca tu código para que te puedan ayudar. Saludos.

Comment: Se me ocurre que las versiones de PHP difieren en los hostings, posiblemente algunas funciones no existen en los otros hostings, pero en ese si, una posible solucion es ver si puedes actualizar la version de PHP de esos servidores.

Comment: Una cosa es que el correo se envíe y otra que sea recibido en su destino, puede llegar a bandeja de entrada, a no deseados o ser rechazado por el servidor, ya sea por malos encabezados o porque el sitio está en una o más listas de spam.

Comment: Una disculpa, ya integre el codigo. Espero puedan ayudarme :(

Comment: Revisa el fichero de errores de php, suele llamarse error.log

Answer (score -2):

Entiendo que cambiaste de hosting, pero veo que tienes dos dominios distintos también (ukoo.mx y sanext.mx).

Para poder enviar mails de forma efectiva con la función nativa de php `mail(...)` el email de origen debe pertenecer al mismo dominio, te paso un ejemplo simple...

```
<?php
$mensaje = '<h1>Hola Mundo!</h1>';
$asunto = 'Mensaje de prueba';
$mail_destino = 'test@gmail.com';

$nombre_from = 'Mi sitio web';
$mail_from = '...@misitio.com'; // Importante, debe pertenecer al dominio, en tu caso (ukoo.mx o sanext.mx)

$nombre_reply = 'Soporte técnico';
$email_reply    = 'soporte@misitio.com'

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ".$nombre_from." <".$mail_from.">\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$nombre_reply." <".$email_reply.">\r\n";
    
if (mail($mail_destino, $asunto, $mensaje, $headers))
{
    echo 'Email enviado OK';
}
else
{
    echo 'No se ha enviado el email.';
}

?>
```

Ojalá sirva de ayuda, saludos!

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], sin ver código cualquier respuesta es mera suposición. Saludos.